# Redemption Date and value of a Debt

Tags: debt, nse-india, maturity

In Indian Stock Market, When I searching for Debt Securities I found the following fields.

```
 Redemption Date
 Redemption Amount
 Conversion Date
 Conversion Amount
```

What does it mean for? Is the Redemption Date is equivalent to Maturity Date?

Comment: What type of security are you looking at?  A convertible bond?

Comment: Can you link the site.